# Magento: cannot get user and cart session info from controller

Tags: php, magento, controller, magento-1.9

I have this piece of code in a controller:

```
public function getiframeAction() {
    if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
        echo "Yes";
    else
        echo "no";
}
```

And it always returns "no", regardless the front-end user is logged in or not. How can I figure out what is going on?

Comment: It's too hard to tell what's going on without more context. What you've posted should work perfectly fine.

Comment: put your code in try.....catch block, so it show if any error.